# "ImportError: No module named seaborn" in Azure ML

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Created a new compute instance in Azure ML and trained a model with out any issue. I wanted to draw a pairplot using `seaborn` but I keep getting the error `"ImportError: No module named seaborn"`

I ran `!conda list` and I can see seaborn in the list

```
# packages in environment at /anaconda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda                  2018.12                  py37_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.6                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.2                    py37_0  
applicationinsights       0.11.9                    <pip>
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0  
astroid                   2.1.0                    py37_0  
astropy                   3.1              py37h7b6447c_0  
atomicwrites              1.2.1                    py37_0  
attrs                     18.2.0           py37h28b3542_0  
babel                     2.6.0                    py37_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
backports                 1.0                      py37_1  
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2  
beautifulsoup4            4.6.3                    py37_0  
bitarray                  0.8.3            py37h14c3975_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
blaze                     0.11.3                   py37_0  
bleach                    3.0.2                    py37_0  
blosc                     1.14.4               hdbcaa40_0  
bokeh                     1.0.2                    py37_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0  
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h035aef0_1  
bzip2                     1.0.6                h14c3975_5  
ca-certificates           2020.7.22                     0    anaconda
cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3  
certifi                   2020.6.20                py37_0    anaconda
cffi                      1.11.5           py37he75722e_1  
chardet                   3.0.4                    py37_1  
click                     7.0                      py37_0  
cloudpickle               0.6.1                    py37_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1  
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0  
conda                     4.5.12                   py37_0  
conda-build               3.17.6                   py37_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-verify              3.1.1                    py37_0  
contextlib2               0.5.5                    py37_0  
cryptography              2.4.2            py37h1ba5d50_0  
curl                      7.63.0            hbc83047_1000  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0    anaconda
cython                    0.29.2           py37he6710b0_0  
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py37h14c3975_1  
dask                      1.0.0                    py37_0  
dask-core                 1.0.0                    py37_0  
datashape                 0.5.4                    py37_1  
dbus                      1.13.12              h746ee38_0    anaconda
decorator                 4.3.0                    py37_0  
defusedxml                0.5.0                    py37_1  
distributed               1.25.1                   py37_0  
docutils                  0.14                     py37_0  
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py37_2  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0  
expat                     2.2.9                he6710b0_2    anaconda
fastcache                 1.0.2            py37h14c3975_2  
filelock                  3.0.10                   py37_0  
flask                     1.0.2                    py37_1  
flask-cors                3.0.7                    py37_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0    anaconda
freetype                  2.10.2               h5ab3b9f_0    anaconda
fribidi                   1.0.5                h7b6447c_0  
future                    0.17.1                   py37_0  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                haa9412d_0  
gevent                    1.3.7            py37h7b6447c_1  
glib                      2.56.2               hd408876_0    anaconda
glob2                     0.6                      py37_1  
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h10f8cd9_2  
graphite2                 1.3.12               h23475e2_2  
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h7b6447c_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1    anaconda
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1    anaconda
h5py                      2.8.0            py37h989c5e5_3  
harfbuzz                  1.8.8                hffaf4a1_0  
hdf5                      1.10.2               hba1933b_1  
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py37_2  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0  
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3    anaconda
idna                      2.8                      py37_0  
imageio                   2.4.1                    py37_0  
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0  
importlib_metadata        0.6                      py37_0  
intel-openmp              2019.1                      144  
ipykernel                 5.1.0            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.2.0            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.4.2                    py37_0  
isort                     4.3.4                    py37_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jbig                      2.1                  hdba287a_0  
jdcal                     1.4                      py37_0  
jedi                      0.13.2                   py37_0  
jeepney                   0.4                      py37_0  
jinja2                    2.10                     py37_0  
jpeg                      9b                   habf39ab_1    anaconda
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py37_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.2.4                    py37_0  
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0  
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py37_0  
jupyterlab                0.35.3                   py37_0  
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                    py37_0  
keyring                   17.0.0                   py37_0  
kiwisolver                1.2.0            py37hfd86e86_0    anaconda
krb5                      1.16.1               h173b8e3_7  
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py37h14c3975_2  
lcms2                     2.11                 h396b838_0    anaconda
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7    anaconda
libarchive                3.3.3                h5d8350f_5  
libcurl                   7.63.0            h20c2e04_1000  
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h14c3975_1    anaconda
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2    anaconda
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0    anaconda
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
liblief                   0.9.0                h7725739_1  
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0    anaconda
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0  
libssh2                   1.8.0                h1ba5d50_4  
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libtiff                   4.1.0                h2733197_1    anaconda
libtool                   2.4.6                h7b6447c_5  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2    anaconda
libxcb                    1.14                 h7b6447c_0    anaconda
libxml2                   2.9.10               he19cac6_1    anaconda
libxslt                   1.1.32               h1312cb7_0  
llvmlite                  0.26.0           py37hd408876_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1  
lxml                      4.2.5            py37hefd8a0e_0  
lz4-c                     1.9.2                he6710b0_1    anaconda
lzo                       2.10                 h49e0be7_2  
markupsafe                1.1.0            py37h7b6447c_0  
matplotlib                3.3.1                         0    anaconda
matplotlib-base           3.3.1            py37h817c723_0    anaconda
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h7b6447c_0  
mkl                       2019.1                      144  
mkl-service               1.1.2            py37he904b0f_5  
mkl_fft                   1.0.10           py37ha843d7b_0    anaconda
mkl_random                1.0.2            py37hd81dba3_0    anaconda
more-itertools            4.3.0                    py37_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h10f8cd9_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                hdf1c602_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0  
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py37h6bb024c_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0  
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0  
nbconvert                 5.4.0                    py37_1  
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0  
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1    anaconda
networkx                  2.2                      py37_1  
nltk                      3.4                      py37_1  
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2  
notebook                  5.7.4                    py37_0  
numba                     0.41.0           py37h962f231_0  
numexpr                   2.6.8            py37h9e4a6bb_0  
numpy                     1.16.2           py37h7e9f1db_0    anaconda
numpy-base                1.16.2           py37hde5b4d6_0    anaconda
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py37_0  
odo                       0.5.1                    py37_0  
olefile                   0.46                       py_0    anaconda
openpyxl                  2.5.12                   py37_0  
openssl                   1.1.1g               h7b6447c_0    anaconda
packaging                 18.0                     py37_0  
pandas                    1.1.1            py37he6710b0_0    anaconda
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hea2e7c5_1  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
pango                     1.42.4               h049681c_0  
parso                     0.3.1                    py37_0  
partd                     0.3.9                    py37_0  
patchelf                  0.9                  he6710b0_3  
path.py                   11.5.0                   py37_0  
pathlib2                  2.3.3                    py37_0  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pcre                      8.44                 he6710b0_0    anaconda
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0  
pexpect                   4.6.0                    py37_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pillow                    7.2.0            py37hb39fc2d_0    anaconda
pip                       20.2.2                   py37_0    anaconda
pixman                    0.34.0               hceecf20_3  
pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py37_1  
pluggy                    0.8.0                    py37_0  
ply                       3.11                     py37_0  
prometheus_client         0.5.0                    py37_0  
prompt_toolkit            2.0.7                    py37_0  
psutil                    5.4.8            py37h7b6447c_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0  
py                        1.7.0                    py37_0  
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37h7725739_1  
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py37_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h14c3975_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h14c3975_9  
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py37h1ba5d50_0  
pyflakes                  2.0.0                    py37_0  
pygments                  2.3.1                    py37_0  
pylint                    2.2.2                    py37_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.25           py37he6710b0_0  
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0    anaconda
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h22d08a2_1    anaconda
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py37_0  
pytables                  3.4.4            py37ha205bf6_0  
pytest                    4.0.2                    py37_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.2.0                    py37_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.3.1                    py37_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.9                h7579374_0    anaconda
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    anaconda
python-libarchive-c       2.8                      py37_6  
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0    anaconda
pywavelets                1.0.1            py37hdd07704_0  
pyyaml                    3.13             py37h14c3975_0  
pyzmq                     17.1.2           py37h14c3975_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1    anaconda
qtawesome                 0.5.3                    py37_0  
qtconsole                 4.4.3                    py37_0  
qtpy                      1.5.2                    py37_0  
readline                  8.0                  h7b6447c_0    anaconda
requests                  2.21.0                   py37_0  
rope                      0.11.0                   py37_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37h14c3975_0  
scikit-image              0.14.1           py37he6710b0_0  
scikit-learn              0.20.1           py37hd81dba3_0  
scipy                     1.2.1            py37h7c811a0_0    anaconda
seaborn                   0.10.1                     py_0    anaconda
secretstorage             3.1.0                    py37_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0  
setuptools                49.6.0                   py37_0    anaconda
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0  
sip                       4.19.24          py37he6710b0_0    anaconda
six                       1.15.0                     py_0    anaconda
snappy                    1.1.7                hbae5bb6_3  
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py37_0  
sortedcollections         1.0.1                    py37_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0  
sphinx                    1.8.2                    py37_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                    py37_1  
spyder                    3.3.2                    py37_0  
spyder-kernels            0.3.0                    py37_0  
sqlalchemy                1.2.15           py37h7b6447c_0  
sqlite                    3.33.0               h62c20be_0    anaconda
statsmodels               0.9.0            py37h035aef0_0  
sympy                     1.3                      py37_0  
tblib                     1.3.2                    py37_0  
terminado                 0.8.1                    py37_1  
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0  
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0    anaconda
toolz                     0.9.0                    py37_0  
tornado                   6.0.4            py37h7b6447c_1    anaconda
tqdm                      4.28.1           py37h28b3542_0  
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py37_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h14c3975_0  
urllib3                   1.24.1                   py37_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py37_0  
wheel                     0.35.1                     py_0    anaconda
widgetsnbextension        3.4.2                    py37_0  
wrapt                     1.10.11          py37h14c3975_2  
wurlitzer                 1.0.2                    py37_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0  
xlsxwriter                1.1.2                    py37_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0    anaconda
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2  
zeromq                    4.2.5                hf484d3e_1  
zict                      0.1.3                    py37_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3    anaconda
zstd                      1.4.4                h0b5b093_3    anaconda
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did the following and wasn't able to reproduce your error:

1. make a new compute instance
2. open it up using JupyterLab
3. open a new terminal
4. `conda activate azureml_py36`
5. `conda install seaborn -y`
6. open a new notebook and run `import seaborn as sns`

#### Spitballing

1. Are you using the kernel, `Python 3.6 - AzureML` (i.e. the `azureml_py36` conda env)?
2. Have you tried restarting the kernel and/or creating a new compute instance?

[image]

Comment: I will try and let you know